# Get max Datetime that is Nullable

Tags: c#

I am trying to  getting the max enddate of a list object using a group by  with the Id and ProductId. But I am getting a  `Nullable object must have a value."` I have tried the HasValue but I get a runtime error? Am I doing this incorrect?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    List<Data> ListOfData = new List<Data>();
    ListOfData.Add(new Data() { Id = 1, ProductId = 5, EndDate = null });
    ListOfData.Add(new Data() { Id = 2, ProductId = 6, EndDate = null });
    ListOfData.Add(new Data() { Id = 3, ProductId = 4, EndDate = DateTime.Now });

    //var ListofUniqueData = ListOfData.GroupBy(r => new { r.Id, r.ProductId })
    //                                                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.EndDate.HasValue ? r.EndDate.Value : null ).First())
    //                                                .Select(i => new { i.Id, i.ProductId, i.EndDate.HasValue ? i.EndDate.Value : null })
    //                                                .ToList();

    var ListofUniqueData = ListOfData.GroupBy(r => new { r.Id, r.ProductId })
                                     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.EndDate.Value)
                                                   .First())
                                     .Select(i => new { i.Id, i.ProductId, i.EndDate.Value })
                                     .ToList();
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    ex.ToString();
  }

}

class Data
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Used for a null : new DateTime() which is 1/1/01.

Comment: Not sure about your intention fully, but try adding a where clause: `.Where(x => x.EndData.HasValue)`, I guess this depends on if you need the null `EndDate` items or not.

Comment: Yes I want to include the null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetValueOrDefault` to get the default value of the type if it's not assigned:

```
var ListofUniqueData = ListOfData.GroupBy(r => new {r.Id, r.ProductId})
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.EndDate.GetValueOrDefault()).First())
    .Select(i => new {i.Id, i.ProductId, i.EndDate.GetValueOrDefault()})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You get the same error with using GetValueOrDefault

Comment: You don't need the null coalescing operator `??`. `GetValueOrDefault()` accepts a parameter that is the default value if it doesn't exist

Comment: Actually `GetValueOrDefault` returns `DateTime.MinValue` if the instance doesn't `HasValue`. Not sure what's going on here...